# Linked List of Running Processes in Kernel 3.*

Tags: process, linux-kernel, scheduling

I want to know next and previous processes of every process,that it's state is "TASK_RUNNING".
In older kernels there is a run_list struct as a member of task_struct. How can I do something like this in kernel 3 ? For example tracing  a list of running processes, but I don't know which struct is defined as such list in kernel 3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In newer kernels, Linux does not maintain a list of all running processes. Instead CFS uses red-black tree of `sched_entity` to store information about running processes.

`task_struct` contains member `se` of type `sched_entity`. Sched entity contains member `run_node` of type `struct rb_node`. This is what you are looking for.

Consult with `include/linux/rbtree.h` for interface of rbtree. To extract `task_struct` from `sched_entity` you can use `container_of(your_se, struct task_struct, se);` (consult with `task_of()` in `kernel/sched/fair.c`).

Comment: You mean that I should traverse the `rb tree` as running processes list?

Comment: Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: If state of a task in task list is 1(`INTERRUPTABLE`) , it doesn't have any `sched_entity`? or it has  `sched_entity` but empty.

Comment: ’sched_entity` is embedded into `task_struct`, so it present in any case. If task is not running, `sched_entity` isn't linked in rbtree. So, you couldn't traverse it.

Comment: Another question: I've seen `cfs_rq` (runqueue) in `kernel/sched/fair.c`.
they contain `sched_entities just ordered by priorities? and there's only one `rbtree` of `sched_entities` devided to multiple runqueues?

Comment: I'm in an enviroment that I only have access to data structures of kernel, in a chain-like way(through linking).For example I have `init_task` pointer address so I can find pointers to `mm struct`,`files struct`...and I can't use functions like `container_of` or `task_of`.Do you know any struct or register that point to `sched_entity`(or have a field of `sched_entity`) so that I can access `rb_tree` without referencing `task_struct`?My final goal is accessing `task_struct `of running processes through traversing `rb_tree` and I'm limited to just using kernel structures and pointers!

Comment: How did you want to traverse linked list without using of `container_of`? If you look at `list_entry()` in `include/linux/list.h`, you will see that `list_entry()` just a macro synonim for `container_of()`. By the way, if you continue expand macros, you will get just a plain C code, without invokation of any function (`just a structures and pointers`, as you want)